# How can I update dropdown in CloudFlare App, based on js object?

Tags: cloudflare-apps

I have a form-builder application, and now I want to create app in CloudFlare, where user can select needed form in dropdown, and "inject" in own website

So, I need to make ajax-request to my API server, it's not a problem.

But next, when I will have object `{form-id: form-name}` I need in some way to add this as option to dropdown in sidebar (in CF App)

I've tried to get content of dropdown by `document.getElementsByTagName("dropdownName")`, but there is an empty NodeList.

This is part of `install.json` with this dropdown:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUffJ.png)

I think, there is easy way to do this, because I seen this functionality in other CF Applications.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was found in Hooks page in video: [Hooks page](https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/developer/docs/webhooks)

When CF App sent hook request to your server, you can modify incoming object, and respond to CF App with this modified object.